# How to make the operation parameter mutate when two or more buttons containing a operation are clicked consecutively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple calculator app using React JS. Most of the things are working as expected. However I want the operator parameter to mutate when two or more buttons containing the operation symbols e.g., "*" , "+" are clicked consecutively.

Below is the relevant portion of code for reference

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      previous: "",
      current: "",
      operation: "",
    };
  }

  clear = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      previous: "",
      current: "0",
      operation: null,
    }));
  };

  delete = () => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      current: this.state.current.slice(0, -1),
    }));
  };

  appendNumber = (number) => {
    const { current } = this.state;
    { current === "0" && this.delete() }
    if (number === "." && current.includes(".")) return;
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      current: prevState.current + number,
    }));
  };

  chooseOperation = (op) => {
    const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;
    if (current === "") return;
    if (previous !== "") {
      this.compute();
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      operation: op,
      previous: prevState.current,
      current: "",
    }));
  };

  compute = () => {
    let computation;
    const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;
    const prev = parseFloat(previous);
    const curr = parseFloat(current);
    if (isNaN(previous) || isNaN(current) || !operation) return;

    switch (operation) {
      case "+":
        computation = prev + curr;
        break;
      case "-":
        computation = prev - curr;
        break;
      case "*":
        computation = prev * curr;
        break;
      case "÷":
        computation = prev / curr;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    this.setState({
      current: computation,
      operation: "",
      previous: "",
    });

    if (operation != null) {
      this.setState({
        previous: `${previous} ${operation} ${current}`,
      });
    }
   }
```

These are the few things that I tried:
Within the chooseOperation method I tried to implement the said functionality using a conditional to update the operator parameter

```
 if (["÷", "*", "+", "-"].some((value) => operation.includes(value))) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        operation: prevState.operation.replace(/[\+\-\*\/]/g, op),
      }));
    } else {
      this.setState({
        operation: op,
      });
    }
```

I also tried this

```
const lastChar = operation.charAt(operation.length - 1);
    if (["÷", "*", "+", "-"].includes(lastChar)) {
      this.setState({
        operation: operation.slice(0, -1) + op,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        operation: `${prevState.operation} ${op}`,
        previous: prevState.current,
        current: "",
      }));
    }
```

I tried to address the issue by writing a conditional within the compute method just before the switch statement

```
if (["÷", "*", "+", "-"].some((value) => operation.includes(value))) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        operation: prevState.operation.slice(0, -1),
      }));
    }
```

However none of the things have worked so far. Neither I've tried nor I want to add any extra parameter since most of the other functionalities work quiet expectedly.

Comment: How long is `operation`?  I would guess from the switch statement that it contains a single character.  It's unclear to me why you are using regex replace, slice and charAt to read from/write to a variable containing a single character.

Comment: tbh initially I tried just this 
// 
if (["÷", "*", "+", "-"].some((value) => operation.includes(value))) { this.setState(() => ({ operation: operation.replace(operation, op), })); }
//
in the chooseOperation method
 the intention was to mutate the operation parameter on consecutive clicks. Thanks for pointing out that using regex replace, slice etc for a single character is unnecessary. In a different version I initialized operation to an array so that it could receive multiple values but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

When the user types in a number (6) followed by an operator (+), all is good. In state we now have `{previous: 6, operation: "+", current: ""}`. But when the user presses another operator the line `if (current === "") return;` kicks in and no update happens.

To fix, we will always allow the operator to be updated, your condition to run compute makes sense where it is, and then update the `previous` and `current` properties when appropriate.

```
chooseOperation = (op) => {
  const { previous, current, operation } = this.state;

  if (previous !== "") {
    this.compute();
  }

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    operation: op,
    previous: prevState.current === "" ? prevState.previous : prevState.current,
    current: prevState.previous === "" ? prevState.current : ""
  }));
};
```

Comment: Omitting if (current === "") return; makes sense and things worked fine after implementing that but there seems to be something wrong with the this.setState() logic proposed by you as it is causing multiple errors e.g.,when the user types in a number (5) followed by an operator (+), all is good. But when the user types the subsequent operand that operand is appended to the current parameter and then the compute method executes that result with the initial operand. For example a simple 5 + 3 is rendered as 53 + 5 .

Comment: post omitting if (current === "") return; if we could modify the logic in a way that it would mutate the operation parameter on consecutive clicks of buttons containing operation symbols then that would fulfill the said objective.
In terms of code what I really want to achieve is  this 
 if (["÷", "*", "+", "-"].some((value) => operation.includes(value))) {
      this.setState(() => ({
        operation: operation.replace(operation, op),
      }));
    }
only it should work as expected

Comment: this version of this.setState is working fine 
 this.setState((prevState) => ({
      operation: op,
      previous:
        prevState.current === "" ? prevState.previous : prevState.current,
      current: "",
    }));
however on subsequent clicks of different operation buttons I am getting NaN as the output. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: update: I  fixed that too, see my answer and please suggest any corrections if any

Answer (score 0):

I kind of got it, the version of chooseOperation mentioned below seems to do the thing

```js
chooseOperation = (op) => {
  const {
    previous,
    current,
    operation
  } = this.state;
  // if (current === "") return;
  if (previous !== "" && current !== "") {
    this.compute();
  }

  this.setState(
    (prevState) => ({
      operation: op,
      previous: prevState.current === "" ? prevState.previous : prevState.current,
      current: "",
    })
  );
}
```

I modified the conditional containing this.compute().